Share.RequestAsync() doesn't work in MAUI app
I use the following code to share text or files in MAUI on iOS. It works fine in my test sample project. But it doesn't work in my other project that adds identifiers, the share dialog doesn't appear. I don't know if it has something to do with the identifiers, I searched some info, but didn't find any solution.
I have added these keys to the Info.plist:
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the photo gallery to save photos and videos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the photo gallery to save photos and videos.</string>

Sharing text:
await Share.Default.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest { Text = "Hello word!!!!!", Title = "Share Text" });

Sharing single file:
string fn = "Attachment.txt";
string file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
    
File.WriteAllText(file, "Hello World");
    
await Share.Default.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
{
    Title = "Share text file",
    File = new ShareFile(file)
});

It works fine in my test sample project.

t don't work in my another project that adding Identifiers, What's the meaning of "adding Identifiers"?

@LiqunShen-MSFT Select the project, double-click the project, enter the project properties, enter ios, and bundle signature

I cannot reproduce it, whether I add Bundle Id or not. You may try adding the Bundle Id to your demo project and identify if it is related. By the way, you may also try placing the Share Task in the MainThread.

@LiqunShen-MSFT Through the analysis of my colleagues, I guess it is because a certain thread in the code affects its pop-up, but I think this is a bug, and now I use ios native code to implement this function. I have posted some code, hope can help someone that encounter same problem.

Through the analysis of my colleagues, I guess it is because a certain thread in the code affects its pop-up, but I think this is a bug, and now I use ios native code to implement this function.
 public partial class SystemServiceHelper
{
   
    public partial void ShareFile(ShareMultipleFilesRequest request);
}


public partial class SystemServiceHelper
{
   
    public partial void ShareFile(ShareMultipleFilesRequest request)
    {
        UIViewController viewController = GetTopViewController();
        if (viewController != null)
        {
            var items = new List<NSObject>();

            foreach (var file in request.Files)
            {
                var fileUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(file.FullPath);
                items.Add(GetShareItem(fileUrl, request.Title));
            }

            UIActivityViewController activityViewController = new UIActivityViewController(items.ToArray(), new UIActivity[] { });
            activityViewController.ExcludedActivityTypes = new NSString[] { };

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone)
            {
                viewController.PresentViewController(activityViewController, true, null);
            }
            else
            {
                UIPopoverPresentationController presentationPopover = activityViewController.PopoverPresentationController;
                presentationPopover.SourceView = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
                presentationPopover.SourceRect = request.PresentationSourceBounds;
                presentationPopover.PermittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any;

                viewController.PresentViewController(activityViewController, true, null);
            }
        }

        NSObject GetShareItem(NSObject obj, string title)
        => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title)
            ? obj
            : new ShareActivityItemSource(obj, title);
    }

    class ShareActivityItemSource : UIActivityItemSource
    {
        readonly NSObject item;
        readonly string title;

        internal ShareActivityItemSource(NSObject item, string title)
        {
            this.item = item;
            this.title = title;
        }

        public override NSObject GetItemForActivity(UIActivityViewController activityViewController, NSString activityType) => item;

        public override NSObject GetPlaceholderData(UIActivityViewController activityViewController) => item;

    }

    private UIViewController GetTopViewController()
    {
        UIViewController viewController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
        while (viewController.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            viewController = viewController.PresentedViewController;
        }
        return viewController;
    }
}

using this service to share files:
  SystemServiceHelper systemServiceHelper = new SystemServiceHelper();
            systemServiceHelper.ShareFile(new ShareMultipleFilesRequest
            {
                Title = Title,
                Files = strings,
                PresentationSourceBounds = IsSharePatient && DeviceInfo.Current.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Tablet
                            ? new Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Rect((int)(this.Width / 2), (int)this.Height - 50, 0, 0)
                            : new Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Rect((int)(this.Width / 8 * 7), (int)this.Height - 50, 0, 0)
            });

